# Stop Python alphabetically ordering dicts within dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

If I create a dict of dicts

```
mydict = {
    'zstuff':{
        'zzz':True,
        'aaa':True
    },
    'astuff':{
        'zzz':True,
        'aaa':True
    }
}
```

Then use 'for' to cycle the dicts

```
for key in mydict:
    for tag in mydict[key]:
        print "{}:{}".format(key,tag)
```

Python outputs

```
zstuff:aaa
zstuff:zzz
astuff:aaa
astuff:zzz
```

Is there any way to get Python to not re-order the second level dicts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python does not order dictionaries alphabetically.  In fact, it orders dictionaries arbitrarily.  If you need a dictionary object that keeps the original order, have a look at the [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) class available in Python 2.7.

Comment: Anything similar for Python 2.6?

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

mydict = {'zstuff' : OrderedDict(zzz=True, aaa=True),
          'astuff' : OrderedDict(zzz=True, aaa=True)}
```